# How can I access html page through flask app and then another html page from the same flask app

Tags: python, html, flask, registration

I'm working on a project, developing it using flask . I want to link a html page with flask app and whenever the user click on register button of html page , I want that it redirect user to another html page through flask app.
How can I do that ?

Comment: what have you tried so far and where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question. You'd like to have a route that takes you to an HTML page and then be able to click a link on that page that will take you to another route.

Here is how you can do that:
The first function in app.py

```
@app.route('/'):
def index():
   return render_template("index.html")
```

Your index.html file may look like this:

```
<body>
<a href="/register">Register</a>
</body>
```

The second function in app.py:

```
@app.route('/register')
def register():
   # Ensure the user reached path via GET
   if request.method == "GET":
      return render_template("another_file.html")

   else:
      pass # Pass is a Python way to say 'do nothing'
```

I included a conditional statement in the second function because maybe you'd like the user to register by submitting a form. If you do this, you may want to do different things depending on the request method.